# Building FMINUIT from source for Octave

Tags: makefile, package, octave

I'm trying to install a package called fminuit http://www.fis.unipr.it/~giuseppe.allodi/Fminuit/Fminuit_building.html
on ubuntu 18.04 machine using Octave. The installation step "make -f Makefile.f2c_lnx.Octave" gives me the following error

WrapIO_Matlab.c:4:10: fatal error: mex.h: No such file or directory

Any idea how to remedy this,

cheers, Damir

Comment: What is your version of Octave? The page you linked says *“Octave version 2.1.x to 3.2.x (and possibly higher): mex file extension is .mex. Use Makefile.f2c_lnx.Octave. NB: building fmuinit for Octave versions prior to 2.3.x (?) requires additional mexlib package supplied by Octave-forge”*

Comment: Its the newest version, 5.1.0 so this should not effect the make command..;

Comment: A lot of things have likely changed between versions 3.2 and 5.1. Did you contact the authors?

Comment: I did, no answer; Shame it was really a package I needed:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build instructions provided by FMINUIT ask you to manually adapt the Makefile to your setup.  I'm guessing you did one of those steps incorrectly.  I'm running Octave 6.0.0 (current development sources) and worked fine:

```
$ wget http://www.fis.unipr.it/~giuseppe.allodi/Fminuit/fminuit-src.tar.gz
$ tar xzf fminuit-src.tar.gz
$ cd fminuit-2011.05.31/fminuit/
# modify Makefile.f2c_lnx.Octave
$ make -f Makefile.f2c_lnx.Octave
$ make -f Makefile.f2c_lnx.Octave install
```

The tricky part is knowing what to modify on the Makefile.  For my case, these were the lines (you need to know the exact Octave version and where you installed it):

```
 #Octave prefix directory (typically /usr or /usr/local): modify if needed
-PREFIX=/usr
+PREFIX=/usr/local
 #major version number
-OCTAVE_MAJOR=2
+OCTAVE_MAJOR=6
 #minor-release version number
-OCTAVE_MINOR=9.12
+OCTAVE_MINOR=0.0
 OBJS= mnintr_wrkrnd.o intrac.o WrapIO_Matlab.o doflush.o
 MINUIT=Minuit_.o
 INSTDIR=../bin/linux_$(ARCH)/octave$(OCTAVE_MAJOR)
```

The fminuit Makefile will "install" inside the fminuit source directory. You may also want to adjust its `INSTDIR` value. You need to adjust your Octave path to use it:

```
>> addpath('/wherever/you/build/fmunuit/fminuit-2011.05.31/bin/linux_x86_64/octave6')
>> fminuit # you probably can figure out how to call this function 
error: fminuit: Too few input arguments
```

Comment: Great, thank you for the effort; It just doesn't work; My path is "/usr/local/octave/5.1.0/"   PREFIX=/usr/local
#major version number
OCTAVE_MAJOR=5
#minor-release version number
OCTAVE_MINOR=1.0
OBJS= mnintr_wrkrnd.o intrac.o WrapIO_Matlab.o doflush.o
MINUIT=Minuit_.o
INSTDIR=../bin/linux_$(ARCH)/octave$(OCTAVE_MAJOR)

Comment: its a fresh ubuntu installation; Am I missing some installation; I have gsl which is needed if correct.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 does not have octave 5.1.0 on its repositories, so it's not a fresh install is it? Did you build Octave 5.1 from source?

Comment: I installed it using this https://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/~cuvelier/Octave/Ubuntu_18-04LTS.html

Comment: Those instructions will install Octave on a non standard location. The octave header files are being installed on `/usr/local/OCTAVE/5.1.0/include/octave-5.1.0/octave` (note the many extra "octave" on the path). Either rebuild octave from source without setting the prefix, or set PREFIX on the fminuit makefile to `/usr/local/OCTAVE/5.1.0`

Comment: thanks! make -f went through after just ./configure installation; Could you just run a simple example1.m on your side to see if  the script runs; Again, there is some path dependence issue for me (doesn't see fminuit);

Comment: I just did and works for me. I expanded the instructions to cover installation steps, not only the build from source steps. You need to call `make` with the "install" target and then adjust the octave path.

Comment: Not to open a new topic, last question; If you look at example1.m it calls a body function from outside .m file; Because fminuit needs a string name for the functions; I have a interpolation handle function actually FUN = @(xi) interpn (x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, A, xi(1), xi(2), xi(3), xi(4), xi(5), "spline");  Would you have an idea how to wrap this handle function to be compatible with this body function syntax;

Comment: If the answer, solves your problem, mark it as solved. I have no clue on how to actually use fminuit function though, your question was the first time I heard of it.